# Export/Import Windows XP wireless configs

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking, export, import

About to rebuild my XP install and figured I'd see if there was a file or interface for collecting the configs for the built in Windows XP wireless manager.

I've looked under the "advance settings" tab and within the properties GUI for each connection and I'm not seeing a way to export the configs.

Clearly if I'm exporting these I'd like to be able to import or override the default config with the backup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Export Wireless settings

1. Launch a command prompt as administrator
2. Type “netsh wlan show profiles”3. Chose profile you want to export.
3. Type Netsh wlan export profile name=”[ProfileName]” Folder=”[Folder Path]”

Example: netsh wlan export profile name=”home-network” folder=”g:\wireless-profile”

Import Wireless Settings Profile

1. Open command prompt with Administrator privileges
2. Type netstat wlan show profile – you will see no profiles defined.
3. Type netsh wlan add profile filename="c:\profiles\WifiProfile.xml”
4. By default it will add to all user profiles, so everybody on this computer can see this new profile and use it.

Comment: +1 @MrStatic: Googled your answer, and it appears right, only problem is that when I run the command "netsh wlan show profiles", I get the following error msgs, which I googled and was unable to find any actionable advice: "The following command was not found: wlan show profiles." -- If I enter "C:\>netsh" the cmd switches to "netsh>", but the CMDs do not work within it. Took a quick read of "netsh>help", but not seeing anything of use. Thanks! (note: I'll +1 any additional comment, cheers!)

Comment: Odd, on 3 xp laptops I have here it worked on them. All SP3.

Comment: +1 @MrStatic: Agree, it's the right answer. I'll just post another question, since it appears unrelated to the current question. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Symantec has a free program called Wireless LAN API can be used to import and export wireless settings on Windows XP.

You can get it here: [How to Capture and Deploy WLAN Profiles (on Windows XP SP2 or SP3)](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/how-capture-and-deploy-wlan-profiles)